# Is there a way to automate computer diagnostics

Tags: hard-drive, memtest86+, portable-apps

What I'm wondering is if there is a way that you can make a cd that boots up [Memtest86](http://www.memtest.org), runs it through, and if there is no error, restarts and then boots up a hard drive checker that verifies the hard drive is okay. Does anything like this exist?

I would like to do this without having to boot into Windows or whatever operating system happens to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would just schedule [Windows Memory Diagnostics](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/diagnosing-memory-problems-on-your-computer) and `CHKDSK` at Windows start up. The results will be stored in Windows Event Viewer.

To schedule disk check on the next boot, run `chkdsk c: /r /f` from an elevated command prompt (Windows Vista/7) or just from the Run dialog (XP). Because Windows won't get full access to the C: for checking, it will ask you permission to run on the next reboot

Comment: I would like to do this without booting into windows.

Comment: Then I guess software like PC-Doctor, Hiren's Boot CD or Ultimate Boot CD will help here.

Comment: Right but there is still the manual part of having to click Enter, etc... with this kind of software. I want it to be completely automated.